# Making AI chase food

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Trying to make the computer go after the food cells in my Agar clone using the same way I made it follow the player but it's not working. Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/eubnqgyg/11/). Relevant snippets:

Modifying the speed if the AI's mass < the player's mass:

```
else if (playerOneMass > computerRadius) {
    this.speedX = (XXYYOfAI[0] / Math.min.apply(null, AIToFoodDists)) * this.speed.x;
    this.speedY = (XXYYOfAI[1] / Math.min.apply(null, AIToFoodDists)) * this.speed.y;
    computerX += 28 * this.speedX / computerRadius;
    computerY += 28 * this.speedY / computerRadius;
}
```

Providing the required values within the for loop that handles the logic for the food:

```
var xx = cell.x - computerX;
var yy = cell.y - computerY;
AIToFoodDists.push(xx * xx + yy * yy);
XXYYOfAI = [xx, yy];
```

If the player is larger, the AI will appear to hunt down a few cells but then the page simply blanks out. So, how would I make it work?

Comment: Can't really see things blanking out in your fiddle.  Getting an error in the console: index.js 171

Comment: Weird. I don't see any errors in mine.

Comment: @Raiden you should probably set your sketch as base every time you want to publish it, so that you don't need to update your SO question every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Worked perfectly (AI *was* following the food, but it simply blanked out after a few seconds) but I was overflowing the maximum call stack size as I was calculating everything inside of the game loop, so I returned only the necessary values (dx, dy) from it and handled everything else in AI.prototype.animate(). (calculating the distance, changing the velocity, etc.) Also managed to make the AI "run away" from the player if gets too close.